# Cannot use a scalar value as an array - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a function in laravel, but when I send a post request the data is updated successfully but I get **cannot use a scalar value as an array** error.

- **Route:**
  Route::post('transfer-gate-request/{id}',[GateRequestController::class,'transferRequest']);
- **Request:** POST: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/transfer-gate-request/333

if I switch to PUT route & request, I get **Undefined array key "gate_department_id"** error

[image]

```
        // Transfer Requests

        public function transferRequest(Request $request, $id)

        {
            $user = Auth::user();

            if ($user->role_id == 4 || $user->role_id == 3) {

                $postData = $request->all();

                $gate_department=GateDepartment::where('id', $postData['gate_department_id'])->first();

                $data = GateRequest::where('id',$id)->update([

                    'gate_department_id' => $postData['gate_department_id'],
                    'department' => $gate_department->name,
                    'waiting_of_approval' => $gate_department->first_approver_id,
                    'approved_first' => null,
                    'approved_second' => null,
                    'approved_third' => null,
                    'first_approve_time' => null,
                    'second_approve_time' => null,
                    'third_approve_time' => null,
                    'approve_counter' => 0,

                ]);
                $data['status']  = 1;
                $data['message'] = 'Gate request transferred successfully!';
                return response()->json($data);

            } else {
                $data['gate_request'] = null;
                $data['message'] = 'You are not authroized to check gate requests';
                $data['status'] = 1;
                return response()->json($data);
            }

        }
```

Comment: `update()` returns a bool, not an array, so you cannot treat it as an array. Create the `$data` array before your if/else check (so the else also has access to it), and either don't assign the `update` to a value, or assign it to a different value